# Libraries and linux Kernel 2.6

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dependencies

Which command i can use to see what my current installed software libraries use from the Kernel 2.6? I want to know this so I can check if it would work fine in case I upgraded my Kernel to 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this command, which is distribution-independent:

`ldconfig -p`

This gives a full list of the libraries installed. If you pipe it to less, you will be able to scroll up or down:

`ldconfig -p | less`

Comment: This just shows the libraries that are directories and candidate libraries stored in the current cache.

Comment: @Lee-Man if you have another command that would work, feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I don't know of any command that can find that information. If there was, porting packages (part of my job) would be so much easier!

Comment: @Lee-Man the only command I know of thats distro-independant is what I answered. I know that rhel based distros use yum list to get a list of all installed libraries but unfortunately the distribution has not been provided in this question...

Comment: @Leb_Broth is actually asking about calls into the _kernel_, not what libraries are being used. For example, the open-iscsi package has a daemon that talks to the iSCSI subsystem in the kernel, passing requests back and forth. Both sides must have the same enumerated list of commands. But how to know if that daemon is talking to the kernel??? I don't know (generically). EDIT: Now I'm not sure what he's asking. Leb?

Comment: @Lee-Man exactly. I want to see what my installed software libraries are calling from the Kernel. Once i know that, then i would be able to see if it can call the same subsystems but this time on an upgraded Kernel, say 3.0.